# How to find URL Rewrite via database?

Tags: magento2, database, url-rewrite

I have 900k URL rewrites in the database, and I need to find one specific URL `/magasin`, the filters aren't helping me because that are too many URLs starting with `/magasin`.

How could I filter it via the database to check its ID or where it's redirecting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to access the database, then you can find it through the `url_rewrite` table.

```
select * from url_rewrite where request_path = 'magasin';
```